# What all can be accessed using Private PAIR?

Tags: patent-search, databases

Suppose I have a private pair account with uspto. Can I see patents filed today by other customers? Or It will show only patents that I have filed ?

Answer (score 0):

It will only show your patents. You can't use it to access unpublished applications filed by others.

Comment: But you can see the entire prosecution history of those that are- so every back and forth with the examiner